# Doctrine connect with mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Is there a way to connect a sqlserver using `php-mssql` DRIVER without a PDO connection on `symfony`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to create your own driver for this purpose.

The `abstract class Doctrine_Connection` defines the way of connect.
On this class, in the method "connect" you can read:

```
if (extension_loaded('pdo')) {
    find valid driver and load into PDO (calling PDO::getAvailableDrivers())
    $found = true;
}
```

If driver is not found ( for example if you submit a dsn like this `mssql_own:host=localhost;dbname=localdb` )  then Doctrine_Connection makes:

```
$class = 'Doctrine_Adapter_' . ucwords("mssql_own");

if (class_exists($class)) {
    $this->dbh = new $class($this->options['dsn'], $this->options['username'], $this->options['password'], $this->options);<br/><br/>
} else {
    throw new Doctrine_Connection_Exception("Couldn't locate driver named " . "mssql_own");
}
```

You need to write this class named on my example "Doctrine_Adapter_Mssql_own" and make a connection with php-mssql.

I hope it helps...